# Golang validator invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: validation, go

#### Package

https://github.com/go-playground/validator

#### Package version eg. v8, v9:

V9

#### Issue, Question or Enhancement:

Question: Followed the tutorial, however, i get `invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference` error

#### Code sample, to showcase or reproduce:

```
import  "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"
var validate *validator.Validate

func V1Register(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var params RegisterReq
    if err := decoder.Decode(&params); err != nil {
        log.Logger.Error("%s", err)
    }

    user := &models.User{
        Id:        10,
        Email:     params.Email,
        Username:  "asddas",
        ProfileId: 22,
        Password:  "rotroot",
        UserType:  10,
    }
    if err := models.CreateUser(user); err != nil {
        log.Logger.Notice("%s", err)
    }

    log.Logger.Info("%s", params.Email)
}

func CreateUser(user *User) (err error) {
    log.Logger.Info("%s", user)

    err = validate.Struct(user)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = database.DBCon.Insert(user)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Mention a comment on a line where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to initialize the validator `validate = validator.New()`

Comment: Add this to comment or add more information to the answer.